# Stop a process when another process starts

Tags: shell-script, shell, systemd, command, compton

I was setting up Bumblee with primus to switch between my discrete/integrated GPUs using the Arch Wiki as a guide when I saw this:

> Note: Since compositing hurts performance, invoking primus when a  compositing WM is active is not recommended. See #Primus issues under compositing window managers.

I use the Compton compositor with i3, so I want to disable Compton whenever primusrun or optirun is invoked and re-enable it when primusrun/optirun are not used.

How could I do this with a bash script or systemd?

I started by writing writing a user level systemd service file for Compton with the idea that I could write a service file for primusrun/optirun that `Conflicts=` with Compton and starts it again after exiting. But the problem is that primusrun/optirun take an application as an argument and run that using the discrete GPU. So their use doesn't seem compatible with starting a service that invokes them.

Any solutions to this? To re-state the core issue: I want to automatically stop the Compton process when primusrun/optirun are started and restart Compton when they are killed.

Comment: How about make primus/optirun a service and add compton shutdown & startup lines?

Comment: I don't think that works because they require an argument that I supply at the command line, e.g `optirun glxgears` or `optirun wine app.exe` -- so if I made them a service and started it with `systemctl start primusrun` then how could I supply an arbitrary argument?

Comment: I don't know anything about Compton, but how about just aliasing `primusrun` to kill Compton first (if that is possible). Then restore it after it quits (`pgrep` to check if any other primusrun instances are running).

Comment: I know how to do the first part -- something like `alias primusrun='pkill compton; primusrun' , but I want some set up where I don't have to manually restart it when primusrun quits. Any ideas? Maybe primusrun could be an alias for a wrapper bash script that kills compton, starts primusrun, ... periodically checks if primusrun is still running?? .., and runs compton if no primusrun is found before exiting.